# Detect isolated "blobs" of color in an image?

Tags: python, image-processing, optimization

I am trying to write code that can detect whether all of the space covered by one color (say, yellow) in a two color image is connected or not, and return how many isolated "blobs" exist. For example, this image would return 0: [image]

since all the yellow space is continuous. However, this image would return 12
[image]

because there are several isolated blobs of yellow that are not connected to the main bulk of the color (I quickly counted 12 smaller blobs by hand).

I have a few ideas on how to do this (for example, looking at the edges and determining when a continuous edge is not touching any others), but most of them feel rather brute-force and I need this to be relatively optimized as I need to compute this on a large number of these images. Are there any existing solutions for this problem that you can point me to that would do something along the lines of what I am describing?

Edit: The original images are [image][image]

I had originally chosen to show screenshots in a colormap that was easier to understand than white on a white website background.

Comment: that yellow-and-purple is a clear sign of those pictures being screenshots of matplotlib plots. please just show us the original data. that spares answerers from having to turn those illustrations back into data.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Added. I had taken screenshots of the images in matplotlib because I thought a white background color (as opposed to yellow) wasn't clear enough with a white website background.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may simply use [cv2.connectedComponents](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaedef8c7340499ca391d459122e51bef5) for getting the number of connected components.

- Use `cv2.inRange` for creating a mask where yellow pixels are 255 and other colors are 0.
  We also have to dilate the mask a little because the the blobs has green border that splits small blobs.

  ```
   thresh = cv2.inRange(img, (0, 200, 200), (50, 255, 255)).
   dilated_thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8))
  ```
- Execute `cv2.connectedComponents`, and get the number of "labels":

  ```
   n_labels = cv2.connectedComponents(dilated_thresh)[0] - 1  # Subtract 1, because the background is counted.
  ```

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('12blobs.png')  # Read the input image
#img = cv2.imread('1blob.png')

thresh = cv2.inRange(img, (0, 200, 200), (50, 255, 255))  # Build a mask where yellow pixels are 255 and other colors are 0
dilated_thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8))  # Dilate thresh because the blobs has green border that splits small blobs

n_labels = cv2.connectedComponents(dilated_thresh)[0] - 1  # Subtract 1, because the background is counted.

print(f'n_labels = {n_labels}')  # 13
```

Comment: According to your updated post, I see you don't even have to use `cv2.inRange` and `cv2.dilate`. Just use `thresh = cv2.imread('12blobs.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`. That is too simple...